# HTML Table th Width Not Displaying Properly

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with one of my Table's setup in my HTML. I have three header titles and for some reason they are not occupying the complete 100% width. However, the body does occupy the 100% width. I'm not quite sure what is going on. I have another table that works just fine. I have attached an image and the html code of the table. The display will still be the same as it is in the image below even if I remove the specified width percentages. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
<table id="timePreferenceTable" class="table-striped" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="34%">Start Time</th>
      <th width="34%">End Time</th>
      <th width="32%">Days</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

[image: HTML-TABLE-TH-BUG]

Comment: Does the `<table>` have a set `width`?

Comment: Try setting the width attribute in your <table> tag: `<table ... width="100%">`

Comment: I've already tried this. It didn't have any affect on the results though.

Comment: Your markup is [not Valid](http://validator.w3.org/), it cannot work. Your code does not contain the content in the screenshot, so a client-side script interferes.

Comment: The "No Time Preference Entered" body content is generated through the jQuery plugin DataTables. In fact, the <tbody></tbody> stays empty and the content is dynamically added with the DataTables plugin. Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: Yes, a `tbody` element must have at least one `tr` element as child, and a `tr` element must have at least one `th` or `td` element as child.

Comment: Actually, it depends on the HTML version. [In HTML5 (CR), the content model of the `tbody` element is "Zero or more `tr` elements".](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/tabular-data.html#the-tbody-element) [Adding the `tr` and `td` elements is backwards-compatible](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3), though. Therefore, if I had written a table script that defines the tbody rows of the table, I would have replaced existing rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set `width="100%"` on your table. I am not sure what your class does. if it is not setting the width 100% then do it.

```
<table width="100%" id="timePreferenceTable" class="table-striped" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
```

Comment: But be reminded that width attribute is not supported in HTML5. You beat me to the punch by the way ;-)

Comment: I've already tried setting the width to 100% on the table, but for some reason it had to affect on the result of the table. The class is only used for styling the body (rows alternate colors, row highlighting, etc.)

Comment: Okay, that that clears some things up now. I tried removing my ID from the table and it worked. So, the issue seems to be coming from the jQuery DataTables setup. Thank you for your help! :)